# Is it a good idea to add a bash code snippet into a bash conf file that is sourced by a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an executable bash script that picks up my external ip address from my modem and uploads it in a dynamic DNS service. The script is accompanied by a configuration file which I source from the script. The configuration file holds values for modem credentials, FQDN for my hostname, modem ip address and "status" website address.

In order to pick up my external IP address, I need to `wget` the "status" webpage from my modem and do some `grep` and `sed` operations to grab the external IP.

So the actual `grep` and `sed` code is also custom for every user.
The main question is: **Canonically** speaking, should such code be present in the conf file or in the script itself.

I am confused because I read this in 2 ways:

1. it is code so it should be in the script
2. it is variable so it should be in the config

I know this may sound like storm in a tea cup, but I would like to learn the right way.

Also, if you believe the right way is (2), I don't know how to declare the code in the configuration file. I tried the following and doesn't work. I've also not been able to find similar examples in the internet.

config:

```
grab_modem_ip='grep "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[[0-9]*" |
    grep tabdata | sed 's/\(.*\)<\/td>.*/\1/''
```

or

```
alias grab_modem_ip='grep "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[[0-9]*" |
    grep tabdata | sed 's/\(.*\)<\/td>.*/\1/''
```

(Notice that I have wrapped the whole command in `'...'` — single quotes.)

script

```
ipaddr=$( wget --user ${modemuser} --password ${modempass} "${modemsite}" -O - 2>/dev/null | "<grab_modem_ip>" )
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `curl http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com` (from http://whatismyipaddress.com/api) be simpler for this? And avoid this question entirely. (Assuming of course that you aren't behind any horrible NATs/etc. but given your situation you can't be.)

Comment: If you expect the configuration to actually change from time to time, putting it into a separate file would prevent you from accidentally changing your code. Other than that, I can't see any advantage compared with including it in your script (I'm assuming that you do not package and distribute your script). When writing Bash software that should be distributed in a package, you would create such a config file. That file would then usually be handled specially during upgrades (e.g. by not overwriting it automatically).

Comment: @EtanReisner What you propose could very well work. I prefer to rely as little as possible on other services. Also, I want to learn from this process. so...

Comment: If your config file is a sourced script then I would probably make `grab_modem_ip` a function and have it do *all* the work and echo the IP address.

Comment: Note that single quotes cannot be nested; your second alias line is equivalent to: `alias grab_modem_ip='grep "[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[[0-9]" | grep tabdata | sed 's/(.)</td>./\1/` and the whole of the `s///` command to `sed` is completely unquoted, _and_ you need to escape the slash in the `</td>` too. To get a single quote into a single quoted string, you have to use the `'\''` sequence (`'…| sed '\''s/(.)<\/td>./\1/'\'`; there's no point adding two single quotes at the end). The first `'` ends the current single-quoted string; the `\'` gives a single quote; then the final `'` resumes the string.

Comment: Have the configuration file define the regexes that vary by user; have the script use the data (emphasis on _data_, not _code_) from the configuration file that does the correct filtering.  Also, use back-ticks to quote code (and hence `$(…)` where you might otherwise use back-ticks in a shell script — which is a good idea, independent of using Markdown).  What we see is otherwise not necessarily what you typed.  The `[[` is probably a typo; harmless in that it matches an open square bracket too, but the data won't contain one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe 2 the correct solution. And I think that your command will solve using this:

```
ipaddr=$( wget --user ${modemuser} --password ${modempass} "${modemsite}" -O - 2>/dev/null | eval "grab_modem_ip" )
```

Comment: nope. `eval` does not do the trick. notice that I have wrapped all the command in conf in `'...'`. It is `grab_modem_ip='...'` . I have also tried `alias grab_modem_ip='...'` and this does not work either

Comment: ¿Can you give me the file that greps the command (or the important part of it)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was "Variables hold data.  Functions hold code.  Don't put code inside variables!" as quoted from [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

so I rewrote grab_modem_ip as a function, that is defined in the conf file.

```
grab_modem_ip()
{
  echo "${1}" | grep "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[[0-9]*" | grep tabdata | sed 's/\(.*\)<\/td>.*/\1/'
}
```

Then invokation in the script is done as

```
modemstatuspage=$( wget --user ${modemuser} --password ${modempass} "${modemsite}" -O - 2>/dev/null )
ipaddr=$( grab_modem_ip "${modemstatuspage}")
```